# Is a dead letter mailbox bound to a Actor instance?

Tags: akka

Or is it bound to the whole actor system? I'm dealing with my actor system and it gets some dead letters when I stopped an actor.I've done in the Event Stream way,but it didn't work.So I wonder if the dead letter mailbox was bound to the actor instance or the actor system.Or maybe there is no need to deal with the dead letters?

Answer (score 1):

Dead letters go through the `DeadLetterActorRef` which is a special actorref that passes the message directly onto the `eventStream` of the `ActorSystem`. By default a regular actor called `DeadLetterListener` listens for `DeadLetters` on the `eventStream` - this is the actor that logs dead letters to the log (unless `akka.log-dead-letters` is set to off, then it is not started when the actor system starts).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.